# Are actor paths case sensitive in Akka?

Tags: path, akka, case-sensitive, akka.net

In Akka I've found that the name of an actor system is case sensitive but I'm so far unable to find any documentation on whether the other parts of the actor paths themselves are case sensitive.

Comment: This should be pretty simple to find out - just create an Actor then try selecting it by its path without and without case equivalency

Comment: I agree, but I don't wish everybody to have to answer the question that way so lets document it here ;)

Comment: Or send a pull request to the Akka docs once you find out. :) I'd check myself but am without access to my dev machine for a few days

Comment: Same here, I'm installing junk without access to my dev tools. I didn't have much luck helping out with Akka.NET documetnation last time I tried... https://github.com/akkadotnet/getakka.net/issues/188